# UNITY.PUN.Spawn point for object

Tags: unity-game-engine

excuse my english.

I have some problem. Earlier i downloaded PUN classic asset from Unity Asset store for understanding multiplayer.
This downloaded asset has a demo "SlotRacer" and its look like this
[image]

There is 4 spawn points and 4 car model with own camera. After connecting each client take spawn point from 0 to 3 and car model from 0 to 3.

I think its implemented by PlayerControl script

```
 private void SetupCarOnTrack(int gridStartIndex)
    {
       
            SplineWalker.spline = SlotLanes.Instance.GridPositions[gridStartIndex].Spline;
            SplineWalker.currentDistance = SlotLanes.Instance.GridPositions[gridStartIndex].currentDistance;
            SplineWalker.ExecutePositioning();

            // create a new car
            CarInstance = (GameObject)Instantiate(CarPrefabs[gridStartIndex], transform.position, transform.rotation);


        // depending on wether we control this instance locally, we force the car to become active ( because when you are alone in the room, serialization doesn't happen, but still we want to allow the user to race around)
        if (PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.PlayerCount == 1)
        {
            this.m_firstTake = false;
        }

        this.CarInstance.transform.SetParent(this.transform);
    }
```

What needs to be written in this script so that the client always takes spawn point 0, and another players takes spawn points from 1 to 3

I tried to add `if(photonView.ismine)` but its don't help.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Maybe try to instantiate the host first and afterwards you add the 3 other clients

Comment: `the client always takes spawn point 0` that doesn't make much sense does it? Every player needs to be on his specific position shared over the network .. you can't just say I always want to be on 0 and the others shifted to other positions .. unclear what you are asking..

Comment: Also checkout where the method gets called and who is deciding the value of `gridStartIndex` .. though it is probably just based on the amount of players in the room..

Comment: **How** should this be even possible? It makes no sense. You can not see yourself always on position 0 ... if lets say player on position 1 goes into the first corner but you display him on position 1 on your device then how do you think you will synchronize the positions and movements correctly over network?!